# Executing script between range of times php

Tags: php

I'm just trying to execute a PHP/sql script when the current time is between two times, something like this

```
// if time() between 16:00:00 and 17:00:00 
// OR  time() between 18:00pm and 19:00pm
// OR time() between 20:00pm and 21:00pm, 
// then  $sql->execute();
// else{ "not executing";
```

I have found I need to use the next logic script, but I just can't handle to make it work.

```
if (time() >= strtotime("23:28:00")) {
   //$sql->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
date_default_timezone_set('YOUR_TIMEZONE');

// Current hour in timezone specified above, taking values 0 through 23.
$currentHour = intval(date('G'));

if ($currentHour === 16 || $currentHour === 18 || $currentHour === 20) {
    /**
     * The stuff you want to execute.
     */
}
```

That would work from 16:00:00 inclusive to 17:00:00 exclusive, 18:00:00 inclusive to 19:00:00 exclusive, and 20:00:00 inclusive to 21:00:00 exclusive.